# Manually change data items in datasource

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-datasource

I have the following datasource with data set to an array.

```
var dataArray = [
    { Id: 1, Name: "RootA", ParentId: null },
    { Id: 2, Name: "ChildA", ParentId: 1 },
    { Id: 3, Name: "RootB", ParentId: null },
    { Id: 4, Name: "ChildB", ParentId: 3 },
    { Id: 5, Name: "RootC", ParentId: null }
];

var treeListDataSource = new kendo.data.TreeListDataSource({
    data: dataArray,
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "Id",
            fields: {
                parentId: { field: "ParentId", type: "number", nullable: true },
                Id: { field: "Id", type: "number" }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This works.

Now I want to change the items in dataArray to:

```
var newData = [
    { Id: 6, Name: "RootD", ParentId: null },
    { Id: 7, Name: "ChildD", ParentId: 6 },
    { Id: 8, Name: "RootE", ParentId: null }
];
```

I tried:

- Just setting it: `dataArray = newData;`
- Setting via the `data()` method in the kendo datasource: `treeListDataSource.data(newData)`

But the grid doesn't display the new values. Instead is just says "no records".

Here's a [demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/OBUSU).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working using the `transport` API. http://dojo.telerik.com/OBUSU/4

```
var treeListDataSource = new kendo.data.TreeListDataSource({
    transport: {
        read: function (options) {
          var data = dataArray;
          options.success(data);
        }
    },
    ...
});

function change() {
    var newData = [
        { Id: 6, Name: "RootD", ParentId: null },
        { Id: 7, Name: "ChildD", ParentId: 6 },
        { Id: 8, Name: "RootE", ParentId: null }
    ];
    dataArray = newData;
    treeListDataSource.read();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some kind of bug that `parentId` field won't look up to modified field `ParentId` after initiation.
You can solve this with create the whole `datasource` definition again.

Your code should be like this:

```
<kendo-treelist id="treelist" k-options="treelistOptions"></kendo-treelist>

$scope.change = function() {
  var treelist = $("#treelist").data().kendoTreeList;
  var newData = [
    { Id: 6, Name: "RootD", ParentId: null },
    { Id: 7, Name: "ChildD", ParentId: 6 },
    { Id: 8, Name: "RootE", ParentId: null }
  ];
  var newDs = new kendo.data.TreeListDataSource({
    data: newData,
    schema: {
      model: {
        id: "Id",
        fields: {
          parentId: { field: "ParentId",  nullable: true },
          Id: { field: "Id", type: "number" }
        }
      }
    }
  });
  treelist.setDataSource(newDs);
};
```